# Enable file sharing over WiFi network

Tags: networking, routing

I have a WiFi network, how can I enable file sharing between computers on that network ? Is this much simpler using a LAN configuration ?

Comment: Which operating systems are the computers on the network running? Wireless is just as simple to share files over as a wired network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should make no difference.  More information might help in giving a detailed answer.  Share the folder or whatever and then connect.  Permissions will need to be considered no matter if wired or wireless.